# polymorphism in C++ and my exam

Tags: c++

I had C++ exam few days back and I got this question and I found it not clear for me, the question was:

> Explain the difference among the terms Polymorphism, virtual function and 
>   overriding. By using example getting the area of shape for rectangle and 
>   triangle, write two different snippet codes to show the implementation of 
>   polymorphism and implementation of polymorphism and virtual function.
>   Give example of output from both snippet codes.

while the definition of polymorphism according to Absolute C++ 5th p669 is:

> Polymorphism refers to the ability to associate many meanings to one 
>   function name by means of the late-binding mechanism. Thus, polymorphism, 
>   late binding, and virtual functions are really all the same topic.

I could understand from this definition that there is no polymorphism without using virtual functions, isn't it? so there are not two different snippet implementation for this question, right ? only one by using virtual function

My question is: Is this a valid question to be asked?

Comment: Yes, this is a very bad question. I wouldn't know how to answer this.

Comment: Could the downvoters explain why they deem this SO question bad, please? I find it interesting and valid to ask.

Comment: the english is poor in the question. It should say 'explain the terms polymorphism, virtual function and overriding - illustrate with example....'

Comment: @cad, I didn't downvote, but in truth, this question does nothing for StackOverflow. It can't be later used as any source of any information, and it just tells us about yet another completely moronic computer science professor.

Comment: although a growing body of proof of the dumbness of CS profs might be useful somewhere along the line (when the revolution comes)

Comment: @pm100, we had this proof 20 years ago. Nothing changed.

Comment: @SergeyA: The question in its current state might not be particularly useful, but it could probably be reworded so it's actually worthwhile (e.g. "What is the difference between polymorphism, virtual functions and overriding?")

Comment: @SergeyA Valid point, but it's nevertheless a good question (in terms of "well-researched" and that stuff) and doesn't deserve a downvote. Or does SO explicitly forbid questions yielding no expansion of knowledge on SO?

Comment: @cad, I hontesly don't know. I didn't downvote, I am just second-guessing ones who did.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> My question is: Is this a valid question to be asked?

No, it isn't regarding the intended answer *"only virtual functions provide polymorphism in c++"* as it seems. The question is too narrow, and misleading.

> > Polymorphism refers to the ability to associate many meanings to one function name by means of the late-binding mechanism. Thus, polymorphism, **late binding, and virtual functions are really all the same topic**.
>
> I could understand from this definition that there is no polymorphism without using virtual functions, isn't it?

Actually you can have polymorphism without `virtual` functions.

It's called ***static polymorphism***, lookup the [CRTP pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) and [SFINAE](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae).

Well, emphasis of **late binding** actually narrows the question for dynamic polymorphism and (pure) `virtual` functions. But IMHO it's still a bad exam and too narrow/unclear question.

Comment: Good catch, though somehow I doubt that is what the exam author means.

Comment: @SergeyA I don't care about dumb tutors/professors.

Comment: @4386427 _"We are dealing with a student!"_ Also their professor does, and seems to mislead the OP badly!

Answer (score 3):

**Polymorphism** is a very abstract term that denotes 3 things in CS/CP :

- **Overloading** (ad-hoc polymorphism). Use a single identifier to denote (in general) different functions
- **Subtyping** (inclusion polymorphism). The preferred form of polymorphism in OOP. The ability of a single function to work with different types of objects, but for which their types are all related by subtyping.
- **Genericity** (parametric polymorphism). The ability of some code to be written in a very abstract way so that many different values of different types can be used, either with unrelated types.

In OOP **overriding** is the ability to redefine in a subtype a function that has been previously defined in a super type.

In C++, **virtual** function member is the qualification of a method to let the subtype polymorphism operates on all subtypes of this type.

```
class A { // A is a polymorphic type (aka contains virtual function)
  public:
    virtual void f() { cout << "A::f()" << endl; } // virtual for polymorphism
};
class B : public A { // public is necessary to obtain subtyping
  public:
    virtual void f() { cout << "B::f()" << endl; } // overriding
};

...
void func(A &a) { // polymorphism can be obtain either on pointers or references types
  a.f(); // polymorphic call, no one can say what will happens here, at least no more than "some function f will be called"
}
...
A a;
B b;
func(a); // guess what will be printed
func(b); // guess what will be printed
...
```